# Visual Studio compiler error: a call to a delegating constructor shall be the only member-initializer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this program(below) that keeps giving me a few compiler errors in Visual Studios. But when I run it with GCC I do not get compile errors. I am really trying to understand how to debug in VS and am having trouble since the compiler errors all point to the last line of the code. Can anyone help me figure out what the errors mean and how to fix them? I also have a pic of the errors that VS gives me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Course
{
   string Course;
   int Credit = 0;
   int Score = 0;
   int Grade = 0;
};

struct Student

{
   int ID = 0;
   string Name = "";
   // Course arrCourse[maxCourseAmt];
     vector <Course>Courses;

};

int isInStudVector(vector<Student>vect, int target)
{
   int i = 0;
       while (i <= vect.size())
       {
           if (vect[i].ID == target)
               return i;
           i++;
       }
       return -1;

}



int main()
{
   fstream inputFile;
   string  fileName = "StudentRecords.txt";
   string token;
   //Student arrStu[9];
   vector<Student>Students;

   inputFile.open(fileName, ios::in);

   if (inputFile.is_open())

   {
       int index = 0;
       int ID;
       string Name;
       string CourseName;
       int Credit;
       int Score;

       while (!inputFile.eof())

       {

           inputFile >> ID >> Name >> CourseName >> Credit >> Score;

           int ii = isInStudVector(Students, ID);

           if (ii == -1) // The student record does not exist

           {
               Students.push_back(Student());

               Students[index].ID = ID;

               Students[index].Name = Name;
               Students[index].Courses.push_back(Course());
               Students[index].Courses[0].Course = CourseName;
               Students[index].Courses[0].Credit = Credit;
               Students[index].Courses[0].Score = Score;

               index++;

           }

           else /// The student exists

           {
               /// Add course and score to the existing student record
           }
       }
       inputFile.close();

   }

   else

       cout << "File cannot be opened.";

   return 0;

}
```

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: hw1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>hw1.cpp
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(28,14): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): error C3511: 'Course': a call to a delegating constructor shall be the only member-initializer
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'Course::Course(Course &&)'
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): error C2664: 'Course::Course(const Course &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'const Course &'
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'const Course'
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(13,1): message : see declaration of 'Course::Course'
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'Course::Course(Course &&)'
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): error C2437: 'Credit': has already been initialized
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'Course::Course(Course &&)'
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): error C2437: 'Score': has already been initialized
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'Course::Course(Course &&)'
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): error C2437: 'Grade': has already been initialized
1>C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\hw1\hw1\hw1.cpp(105,1): message : This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'Course::Course(Course &&)'
1>Done building project "hw1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: I've edited the question so the title will more likely match future google searches. I also removed the screenshot to only keep the textual output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you hit a compiler bug. [Both GCC and Clang compiles your code correctly, but not MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/Mbf7ed).

However, the fix is simple. It seem MSVC don't like members that has the same name as the class. Simply changing `Course` to `Name` will do the trick:

```
struct Course
{
   string Name;
   int Credit = 0;
   int Score = 0;
   int Grade = 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I never would have worked that one out!!!

Answer (score 3):

VS does not like the member `string Course` in the `struct Course`, because "Course" is the implicit name of the constructor. Rename either the member or the struct name.